# have a codigniter session alternative way which behave as like session and how to implement?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently i am facing problem in codeigniter session size. some data doesn't save in session variable  but i need this. i don't find any solution over googled. Here's my some session code.
first i create session for login:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('member_loged', TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata('uid', $uloged->id);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_name', $uloged->user_name);
$this->session->set_userdata('email', $uloged->email);
```

second session code for exam :

```
$onlineexam = array();

$ukey = time();
$uid = $this->session->userdata('uid');
$onlineexam['uid'] = $uid;
$onlineexam['examid'] = $eid;
$onlineexam['ukey'] = $ukey;
$onlineexam['onlineexamdate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

foreach($allque as $que):

$quid = $que['id'];
$qa['queid'] = $quid;  
$onlineexam['allq'][] = $qa;
$this->session->set_userdata('onlineexam', $onlineexam);

endforeach;
```

Third sesion add in online exam after click by ajax:

```
$onlineexam = $this->session->userdata('onlineexam');
$ans['queid'] = $queid; 
$ans['ansid'] = $ansid;
$ans['flag'] = $checkans;
$onlineexam['allanswer'][] = $ans;
$this->session->set_userdata('onlineexam', $onlineexam);
```

in allanswer variable fill with some data and miss maximum data

Comment: is it sending you some error ?

Comment: You need to switch from the cookie store to the datgabase store for codeigniter sessions. But this is more a support than a programming questiion so I'd say this is off-topic. Also has the "request to google it for me" potential, so -1.

Comment: No error show but when i retrieve some information from session variable and its missed @Moyed Ansari

Comment: i already try session store in database but its failed. So i want to an advice and implemented way for this purpose. thats all @hakre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sessions stored in the cookie? If so, you are limited to 4kb. Switch to database sessions and you can store an endless about of information